# Timer doesn't start

Tags: c#, timer

I've simply added a timer (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) to form in my app. When i call `Timer1.Start();` from an EventHandler of IE's object's (`SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`) `DocumentCompleted` event like this:

```
    private void internetExplorer_DocumentComplete(object sender, ref object args)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

It doesn't throw any kind of exception, simply doesn't start. If I call the method from any other functions, the timer starts.
How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some code example would help.

Comment: I would recommend against using the System.Windows namespace outside of WinForms applications.

Comment: Perhaps a cross-thread problem?

Comment: code examples are always helpfull. Maybe it has to do that when you start the timer from the eventhandler, you are not on the application's main thread. Try using Invoke...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing the call like this.  As others have mentioned, you're probably calling from a different thread than who owns the timer.

```
    private void internetExplorer_DocumentComplete(object sender, ref object args)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action<object, object> del = internetExplorer_DocumentComplete;
            this.Invoke(del, sender, args);
            return;
        }
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. :)  (on a mission to get over 2000 today...)